# unable to get check box value in android

Tags: android

```
public class FragSettings extends SherlockFragment {
    CheckBox notificationcheckbox;
    Button savebutton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_settings, container, false);
        notificationcheckbox = (CheckBox) container
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        savebutton = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        addListenerOnChkWindows();

        return view;
    }

    public void addListenerOnChkWindows() {

        notificationcheckbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bro, Notifcation:)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        savebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                result.append("Linux check : ").append(
                        notificationcheckbox.isChecked());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my code i want set notification value and get in another class. but i am unable to set and get value in another class basically i want to implement setting part in android . please look and tell me solution am trying but its showing Error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your function:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_settings, container, false);
    notificationcheckbox = (CheckBox) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    savebutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    addListenerOnChkWindows();

    return view;
 }
 public void addListenerOnChkWindows() {

    notificationcheckbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (notificationcheckbox.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bro, Notifcation:)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: how about save button function

Comment: its ok but i want when it unchecked then also it should print follwing thing is uncheckd

Comment: then add else part in your if condition..that's it..!

Answer (score 0):

Change this code, Instead of  using container use inflate view you will get

```
  notificationcheckbox = (CheckBox) view
            .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```